# On Postgres-XC start getting sudo: unknown user: postgres sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin?

Tags: linux, postgres-xc

Installed Postgres-XC

```
 $>sudo apt-get install postgres-xc
```

then

```
$ postgres -V
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
```

after this I tried to start the Postgres server using following methods.

method 1

```
$>sudo postgres --coordinator -D DN2

"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.
```

method2

```
$ sudo -i -u postgres

sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

and installed pgadmin3 also from there I want to connect Postgres server .

what is the correct way to start the Postgres-XC server?

Is the above procedure correct? if yes what is wrong with it?

Comment: postgress-xc is different from postgressql. In the above process default created user is postgres-xc not the potsgres.  And more over its easy to install the postgress by using enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Postgres's, the best way to is using enterpriseDB.

To see some  downloader installer section from the below URL.

```
https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/
```

To download the Postgres

```
http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#linux
```

To install the Postgres

```
http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/02/20/how-to-install-latest-postgresql-9-x-on-linux-mint-16-petra-3264bit-linux-easy-guide/
```